# System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) throws exception Source:mscorlib

Tags: c#, exception, windows-forms-designer

I have an windows Form Application who throw this exception:

```
TargetSite:  System.Object CreateInstance(System.RuntimeType, Boolean, 
Boolean, Boolean ByRef, System.RuntimeMethodHandleInternal ByRef, Boolean ByRef)
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation
Source: mscorlib

StackTrace:
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean 
publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, 
RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean 
skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean 
skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
at Pronet.Login.FrmLoginMetro.LoadMDI_Form()
```

This happens only in one machine, I have a lot of machines who work without this error, so I'm not be able to debug in development machine..

this is my code:

```
 void LoadMDI_Form()
    {
        try
        {
            Application.DoEvents();

            lblStatus.Text = "Carregando objetos do Banco...";
            lblStatus.Refresh();
            ((Form)Activator.CreateInstance(tipo)).Show();
            Hide();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageFactory.CreateMessage(EstiloMensagem.WindowsForm).ErroInesperado(ex, Perfil.CodUsuario, Perfil.NomeUsuario);
            Application.Exit();//fecha o sistema  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are your able to fetch inner exceptions?

Comment: add a global error handler and do a ToString on the exception object. The msg you got seems like its from event viewer

Comment: You need to improve the code that reports exceptions.  It can't show the InnerException, you need it.  Exception.ToString() is invariably useful.

Comment: well, what is `tipo`, and what is the `ex.InnerException.Message`? this sounds like a `TargetInvocationException`, which is one of those cases where the interesting info is in the `.InnerException`

Comment: tipo is typeof(Form)

Comment: I will try capture InnerException..

Comment: I Changed the code to capture innerexception, but innerException is null :/

Comment: @fsbflavio don't manually capture inner exception. Just do a .ToString() on the exception that you got.

Comment: Thanks! with **ex.ToString()** I've got a better error description. I'll search for a solution based on it.

Comment: How can I close this question?

Comment: With ex.ToString() I've got a better error description. I'll search for a solution based on it.